# Sendgrid change the hyper links within emails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, anchor, sendgrid

SendGrid is removing my domain name from the anchor tag.
I am sending an email through Sendgrid, but Sendgrid is changing the href link, it's replacing my domain name like this

https://url4294.my-domain/ls/click?my-domain.com/ls/click?upn=Ks8-2Fpv9c1mw-2B1-2Beu-2FCHPBtVi31e-2BipKH0NupcMkGX-2FHelULPDwqDbYad-2Fh-2B7-2BhZaTw5EfEDIf6-2FfGWpcuGa1GCCyMmdd9Suky9Fz73LTWbK6H-2FGr2d-2BLgDI6ouUD7pAAbCPDqCNZISCDitJlIiOY2x1ZcpASSrlas36YTJLn-2BStqFhB2DM-2Fg6LSdzwTwNP6eM-2BXKZVwOFD87BXJ2XK3F0xxN3FTstaMQaYvFpLQjjcl7sJm-2BRizYNHBQ-2BLIofgdgl0Av0to-2F7R9k-2Bj8ljVRKmw-3D-3DSIyx_Bx-2BpwuArgZDIXtl3vKulmCDo3q4OtrrRYCxYDMjGArHXyYb4VkcjC3-2BTfvDQQ1TfTH-2FxRMAwqHVUplQgYg2nxW-2FTkgbGGySH6aZD-2F9JOJmz1qu6Pq9pMyDdM6TZvww6gsNva8k4l-2B9jZ4yRaq35sUYBBF4JqXby5FPvmkHJnN4RdBNWYJCjGCi2ueDPm2Bqqe0lsU7SQXHm8-2FBhQPfoKQg-3D-3D

Actual my links look like this

https://my-domain.com/reset_password_token=/f7518bcf1b6fcc1230b0b9680f18d87fedff92e7f9ed5d275ee6bb376cbef7b8

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hyper link Issue within email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74260177/hyper-link-issue-within-email)

Answer (score 0):

If you use Cloudflare as DNS, then the Sendgrid setting `Sender Authentication > Link Branding > CNAME records` should be placed in Cloudflare DNS, not in hosting DNS. Otherwise, the mentioned issue appears.