# hyper link Issue within email

Tags: html, html-email, sendgrid, cloudflare, sendgrid-api-v3

I am sending an email through Sendgrid, but link is changed and on click on link it gave error.

Link to page:
expected link:
https://my-domain.com/reset_password_token=/f7518bcf1b6fcc1230b0b9680f18d87fedff92e7f9ed5d275ee6bb376cbef7b8

link intercepted at this point
https://url4294.my-domain/ls/click?my-domain.com/ls/click?upn=Ks8-2Fpv9c1mw-2B1-2Beu-2FCHPBtVi31e-2BipKH0NupcMkGX-2FHelULPDwqDbYad-2Fh-2B7-2BhZaTw5EfEDIf6-2FfGWpcuGa1GCCyMmdd9Suky9Fz73LTWbK6H-2FGr2d-2BLgDI6ouUD7pAAbCPDqCNZISCDitJlIiOY2x1ZcpASSrlas36YTJLn-2BStqFhB2DM-2Fg6LSdzwTwNP6eM-2BXKZVwOFD87BXJ2XK3F0xxN3FTstaMQaYvFpLQjjcl7sJm-2BRizYNHBQ-2BLIofgdgl0Av0to-2F7R9k-2Bj8ljVRKmw-3D-3DSIyx_Bx-2BpwuArgZDIXtl3vKulmCDo3q4OtrrRYCxYDMjGArHXyYb4VkcjC3-2BTfvDQQ1TfTH-2FxRMAwqHVUplQgYg2nxW-2FTkgbGGySH6aZD-2F9JOJmz1qu6Pq9pMyDdM6TZvww6gsNva8k4l-2B9jZ4yRaq35sUYBBF4JqXby5FPvmkHJnN4RdBNWYJCjGCi2ueDPm2Bqqe0lsU7SQXHm8-2FBhQPfoKQg-3D-3D

Comment: Have you tried turning off tracking? Tracking might be causing your link to give errors

Answer (score 0):

Turn off [tracking settings](https://docs.sendgrid.com/ui/account-and-settings/tracking) within Sendgrid.

This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40687167/9465781) and includes more info, so I recommend checking it out.

Also, please refrain from posting [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74233504/sendgrid-change-the-hyper-links-within-emails), thank you!